# Microsoft Graph : read outlook emails for owner

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a background application and need to read outlook messages for user.

I created an application on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com after logging under this user.

I set the following permissions:

[image]

Then I try to create subscription:

[image]

where name of user in `Resource` property is the same as I logged to system when I had been creating application on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

But I get

> "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: No applicable user context claims found.]",

what is wrong?

Comment: Have you executed Admin Consent for this application yet?

Comment: it works for this application, thank you!